# Puppeteer, как правильно сделать хелпер (или дефолтный селектор)? незнаю как правильно назвать

Tags: javascript, test-automation, puppeteer

Я использую тестовый дата аттрибут  "data-test-id"
пример :
`data-test-id="button"`

Я хочу создать хелпер(незнаю как правильно назвать) чтобы ненадо было каждый раз писать "data-test-id"

а написать гет "что-то там" и подставить нужное значение типа что-то `data-test-id="${button}"` или может

```
DATA_ATTRIBUTE = `data-test-id=`

this.DATA_ATTRIBUTE+"button"
this.DATA_ATTRIBUTE+"field"
```

Подскажите какие есть варианты решения моей задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужна всего лишь строка с постоянным префиксом и переменным окончанием, тогда проще всего через функцию:

```js
function data(value) {
  return `data-test-id="${value}"`;
}

const attribute = data('button');

console.log(attribute);
```